# Flipping Shape Over Axis in JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

Here is the link to what i'm trying to do. I want to flip the blue bars to face to opposite way on the male side then I will fill in the female side as normal. This will create a tornado chart. I've been working on this for hours and I cant figure it out. I'm using Raphael JS.

http://math.mercyhurst.edu/~cmihna/DataViz/Butterfly.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finished up reviewing your website's source code. No need for transforms, or anything of the such. Just some simple math added to your graph generating for-loop.

**Your Code below**

```
ind = 0
        for (var key in gender) {   // loop over all possible gender
            for ( var i = 0; i < people.length; i++ ) { // loop over people
                if (people[i][key] != 0) { 



                    var barmale = paper.rect((w+leftPadding-rightPadding)/2,topPadding + vs*0 + i*vs, people[i][key],vs)
                    barmale.attr({'fill': '#0000A0', 'stroke-width':1})


                    var barfemale = paper.rect((w+leftPadding-rightPadding)/2, topPadding + vs*0 + i*vs, people2[i][key],-vs)
                    barfemale.attr({'fill': '#FFC0CB', 'stroke-width':1})

                    barmale.scale(1,-1)

                    //var dp = paper.circle(leftPadding + ind*hs + 0.5*hs, topPadding + vs*0.5 + i*vs, people[i][key])
                    //dp.attr({ 'fill': colors[ind] })
                    barmale.id = people[i][key] + " " + gender[key] + " people in this age range"
                    barmale.hover(hoverStart, hoverEnd)

                    barfemale.id = people[i][key] + " " + gender[key] + " people in this age range"
                    barfemale.hover(hoverStart, hoverEnd)


                }
            }
            ind++
```

**My Code Below**

```
ind = 0
for (var key in gender) {   // loop over all possible gender
    for ( var i = 0; i < people.length; i++ ) { // loop over people
        if (people[i][key] != 0) { 



            var barmale = paper.rect((w+leftPadding-rightPadding)/2 - people[i][key],topPadding + vs*0 + i*vs, people[i][key],vs)
            barmale.attr({'fill': '#0000A0', 'stroke-width':1})


            var barfemale = paper.rect((w+leftPadding-rightPadding)/2, topPadding + vs*0 + i*vs, people2[i][key],vs)
            barfemale.attr({'fill': '#FFC0CB', 'stroke-width':1})

            barmale.scale(1,-1)

            //var dp = paper.circle(leftPadding + ind*hs + 0.5*hs, topPadding + vs*0.5 + i*vs, people[i][key])
            //dp.attr({ 'fill': colors[ind] })
            barmale.id = people[i][key] + " " + gender[key] + " people in this age range"
            barmale.hover(hoverStart, hoverEnd)

            barfemale.id = people2[i][key] + " " + gender[key] + " people in this age range"
            barfemale.hover(hoverStart, hoverEnd)


        }
    }
    ind++
```

You can see that I am subtracting the value of the Males from the placement on the graph. This causes the offset to "flip". Then, I modified the code a bit more the bring the female graph into the picture and properly label it.

Please let me know if any questions.

**Proof below**
[image: Proof of Working Code]